# Makefile for C# console programs

Tags: c#, makefile

How can I write a Makefile (gnu make) to compile a C# console project that has several files. I understand that there are other build tools, but my course requirements force me to submit a makefile.

Comment: -1: There are plenty tutorials available online that teach how to write a makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the compiler for the C#, with providing right arguments to it.

[Here](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/12/c-tutorial-for-beginners/) you can find examples

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx):

> If you are working on a computer that only has the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK),
>   you can use the C# compiler at the command line if you use the **SDK Command Prompt**, which is
>   available from the **Microsoft .NET Framework SDK** menu option.

Or simply install the .NET Framework (thank to the @Alexei Levenkov).

Comment: What is the lightest package that should be installed to get the C# compiler. Is Visual Studio needed?

Comment: Actually C# compiler is part of .Net runtime, you don't need any SDK to run it - just regular .Net install of any version will do. Path would look like %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Updated the answer. Thank you. I forgot about this variant.

Comment: Same reason I downvoted @Tigran's answer. The question was about a makefile; the answer wasn't. It's fine to comment that technically a makefile isn't really needed, but the OP stated that he/she is required to produce one, so any answer should involve hints how to write one. (Notwithstanding the fact that I think the question doesn't belong here at all. The OP can easily find the needed info with a short web search.)

Comment: @eriktous actually it's ridiculously difficult to find guidance on how to write a makefile for GNU Make to compile a c# project for Mono. Every source would tell you to do it other way.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a Visual Studio installed just create a batch file and call

```
devenv your_project_complete_path
```

Or use [MsBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163589.aspx) as provided in sample.

or use [csc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) as provided in sample.

Comment: -1: OP asked about Makefiles and specifically excluded other build tools.

Comment: @eriktous: in the aswer above you read: "you can simply use a compiler for C#". To me it seems that we are talking about CSC. Where is my answer so wrong? Do you use some other compiler fir C#?

Comment: The question was not about which compiler to use, but how to write a makefile to invoke the compiler.

Comment: @eriktous: if you follow the links provided you will see how to use compiler from CommandLine, so you can define it in make file, as requested. This is EXACTLY the same thing which is talking about an answer above. Don't really understand your point.